# Wicket: Palette, can´t initiate ListModel?

Tags: java, wicket

I think this is a very newbee question but I dont get it.. Im trying to add a palette of wicket to my page.

according to [wicket examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?0&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.Index&source=PalettePage.java) and [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-palette-example/) it should be realy easy.

I stuck at this

```
List<Category> listCategory = new ArrayList<Category>();
listCategory = catDao.getAll(Category.class);
List<Category> selected = new ArrayList<Category>();

IChoiceRenderer<Category> renderer = new ChoiceRenderer<Category>("title","id");

    final Palette<Category> palette = new Palette<Category>("palette",
            new ListModel<Category>(selected),
            new CollectionModel<Category>(listCategory),
            renderer, 10, true);
```

netbeans says that

```
ListModel is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Why isnt this working for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably imported Swings [`ListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) accidentally which is an interface. Import `org.apache.wicket.model.util.ListModel` ensuring that the `wicket-core` [jar file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/wicket/wicket-core/6.17.0/wicket-core-6.17.0.jar) is on the classpath.